# How to change the colour of line below TextField ,whenever a wrong input is made in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to change the color of the text input filed when a wrong value is entered, e.g an invalid email is entered then the **TextField** will become red and the line below text field also becomes **red**, I want to make it **orange**.

Answer (score 2):

Same can done with - `decoration: InputDecoration`

```
TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0,color: Colors.orange),
                focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: 
                Colors.orange)),
         )
```

Answer (score -1):

text field have a default delegate call editingchanged from story board, hope you can work with that, and also please elaborate your code if you require more information

write this in "viewdidload"

```
textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

And,

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField){
    //do your changes
}
```

whenever there is a change in text field above function will be called

Comment: This is an iOS answer and a Flutter answer is requested.